# Time compexity of a function that is reversing a string

Tags: javascript

just want to know the time complexity of this function!

```
     function reverse2(str) {
       console.log(
         str
          .split("")
          .reverse()
          .join("")
        );
     }
```

this function is traversing a string 3 times? so is the complexity n^3?  or what?

Comment: I don't know the implementation details, but this surely isn't `O(n^3)` (which would be unusably slow in practice). Even if it really goes over the string 3 times that's only `O(n)` (which is usually acceptable except for huge inputs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this function is traversing a string 3 times? so is the complexity n^3?` traversing the string 3 times would be `O(3 * n)` which essentially is the same as `O(n)`. `O(n^3)` would be if you traversed the entire string and for every character you traversed the string again, and for every character you traversed the string once more. So in essence 3 loops within each-other.

To clarify, yes you are traversing the string 3 times, so the complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: we used str.split(" ").reverse()
...lets say split and reverse are two loops, so these will be nested or one after the other? because of dot ( . )

Comment: After each-other, they will happen sequentially.